# Difference between void and (int, string, etc.)

Tags: java, return-value

Whats the difference between

```
public void Sum()
```

and

```
public int Sum()
```

I tried searching on Google/YouTube and I've learned that `public int Sum()` needs a `return` statement. I'm using `return` a lot, but I really dont know what is the use of it on methods.

Comment: Or the Oracle Java tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public void sum()` doesn't return any value e.g. below:

```
  public class Calculate{
     private int sum = 0;

     public void performSum(){
         sum(3,4);
         System.out.println("sum="+this.sum);
     }

     public void sum(int value, int value2){
           sum = value1+ value2;
           return; //optional
     }
  }
```

`public int sum()` must return a value of type `int` e,g, below:

```
  public class Calculate{

     public void performSum(){
         int sum = sum(3,4);
         System.out.println("sum="+sum);
     }

     public int sum(int value, int value2){
          return value1+ value2;
     }
  }
```

Comment: public void which returns an int...?

Comment: @gokcehan How can you know that? And if I just let it go, it would teach this guy the wrong thing. You're supposed to downvote wrong answers

Comment: It was not that wrong. `public int sum() must return a value of type int e,g, below:` was written in the description just above the sample code. There was a typo in the sample code only. It was also obvious in the answer, that second sample code was referring  `public int sum()` and not the `public void sum()`  Thanks to @gokcehan for the correction. I think we can leave it now as response is already corrected.

Answer (score 4):

`void` methods do not return anything - they simply perform an action. `int` methods on the other hand, as the name suggests, return an integer value.

For example,

```
public void sum() {
    System.out.println("1 + 1 = 2"));  // we don't return anything
}

public int sum() {
    return 1 + 1;  // we return an integer
}
```

Similarly,

```
public double sum() {...}  // returns a double

public boolean sum() {...}  // returns a boolean

public String sum() {...}  // returns a String

...  // you get the idea
```

---

As a note, it is convention to start method names with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

first one doesn't return anyhting you may use this if you want to say just print the added values.

Second method returns an `int` you use this kind of method if you want that added value some where else in your program so that you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

void methods do not return anything - they simply perform an action. While int, double, boolean, String methods return integer, double, String  value.

For example,

```
public void sum() {
    System.out.println("1 + 1 = 2"));  // we don't return anything
}

public int sum() {
    return 1 + 1;  // we return an integer
}
```

Similarly,

```
public double sum() {...}  // returns a double

public boolean sum() {...}  // returns a boolean

public String sum() {...}  // returns a String
```

The first method type void sum() just perform an action call a method println() and the purpose of this method is to print a String value.

Here is another example:

```
void bark() {
    System.out.println("Woof-Woof");
  }
```

You will see that print out on your screen: Woof-Woof
because the body of bark() method has inside the println() method and this method has a statement "Woof-Woof" type String, so bark() method is performing an action: calling println() method, and println() method is returning a String statement.

`System.out.println` is composed of three parts:

1) System – is a final class in java.lang package.

2) out – is a static member field of System class and is of type PrintStream.

3) println() – is a method of PrintStream class.

If you want to know more about System.out.println here is a link that explains with some details:

http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/

I hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

when u dont want to return any thing from the function then use- void
if u want to return integer then use int

```
public void sum() {
    System.out.println(5+6);
}

public int sum() {
    return (5 + 6);
}
```

```
public void sum() {
        System.out.println(5+6);
    }
```

this function can be called as

```
sum();
```

```
public int sum() {
        return (5 + 6);
    }
```

this function can be called as

```
int a=sum();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Naming Convention:** `Always remember that your method name should start with the small letter.` Use camel case for method names.

**void:** This method does not return anything.

**int:** This method returns an integer.

Please read a good java book, I suggest you to go for `Java - Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt.`

Comment: No, don't read books by Herbert Schildt, since he doesn't follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score -2):

```
    public class Prime 
    {

        void dispaly()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<100; i++)

            {
                boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

                for(int j=2; j<i; j++)
                {

                    if(i%j==0) 
                    {
                    isPrimeNumber=false;
                    break;
                    }

                }



            if(isPrimeNumber)
            {

                System.out.print(i + " ");

            }


        }


        }

        void dispaly1()
        {
            System.out.print("\n");

            for(int i=1;i<100; i++)

            {


                for(int j=2; j<i; j++)
                {

                    if(i%j==0) 
                    {


                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                    break;

                    }

                }




            }


        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Prime p= new Prime();
            System.out.print("The Prime Numbers are : ");
            System.out.print("\n");
            p.dispaly();
            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.print("The Composite Numbers are : ");
            p.dispaly1();

        }
    }
```